Laravel Route resource destroy not working with react js as front
Delete item from table in react does not work.
I'm using axios with
laravel as backend.
Here are the details:
const handleDelete = (user)=>{
    if (!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")) {
        return
      }
    axiosClient.delete(`/members/${user.id}`)
    .then(() => {
      getUsers()
    })
}

<tbody>
            {users.map((user,key)=>{
              return ( <tr key={key} >
                <td class="p-2 md:p-4">{user.id}</td>
                <td class="p-2 md:p-4">{user.Employee_Name}</td>
                <td class="p-2 md:p-4">{user.User_Name}</td>
                <td class="p-2 md:p-4">{user.Date}</td>
                <td class="p-2 md:p-4">{user.Post}</td>
                <td class="p-2 md:p-4">{user.Team}</td>                   
                <td >
                <button onClick={ev=> handleDelete(user)} >
                Delete  
                </button>

axiosClient:
import axios from "axios"
const axiosClient =axios.create({
baseURL:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api`
})

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((conf)=>{
const token = localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")
conf.headers.Authorization=`Bearer ${token}`;
return conf;
});

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use((resp)=>{
return resp
},
(error)=>{
const {resp}=error;
if(resp.status === 401){
    localStorage.removeItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
}
throw error;
}
);

export default axiosClient;

routes API:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\api\apiController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
Route::post('logout',[AuthController::class,'logout']);    
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
   

    Route::apiResource('/members',apiController::class);

});



Route::post('login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::post('register',[AuthController::class,'register']);

controller:
public function destroy(Employees $employees )
{

    $employees->delete();
  
    return response("",204); 
 }

I try to delete item in table but it does not work; I don't know why.

There may be many reasons for this. Sharing the error instead of sharing your code makes it easier to detect the error. Maybe it's the Laravel route cache, maybe your remote address is wrong. If you are doing API development, you should always cross-check with Postman.
